# Database conflicts between 2 Laravel apps on same server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

I have two applications (App 1 and App 2) on the same server (Laragon) with two separate databases.  They each have separate app keys and I've changed the name of the session variable so that they're unique, but for some reason I keep getting data from App 2 saved to the App 1 database. It doesn't happen all the time, maybe 1 in every 100 commits to the database but I have no idea why it would be happening. The apps were originally the one code base but I had to separate them due to differences at both the locations the apps are for.

Every now and then you get logged out for no reason as well. I'm using the default authentication system in Laravel 5.

Has anyone had anything like this happen before, or have I missed any other settings that should be different between the apps?

The apps are on a Windows server sitting inside Laragon and the database is an MSSQL database.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you changed the session cookie name in your `session` config?

Comment: Yes, both session cookie names are unique.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution for this? I could give you one.